# Removing the Digital Clock while on Full Screen in WatchKit App

Tags: sprite-kit, watchkit, watchos-5

I am creating a game for the Apple Watch. I was able to set the interface controller to full screen in the attributes inspector (which also required having a SpriteKit Scene in the interface controller). The full screen functionality does work, but unfortunately the default digital clock on the watch still exists at the top right of the screen. Is there a way to remove the clock while the game is being played? Would be nice to reclaim as much real-estate as possible on the small screen. Thanks!

I noticed a few apps already do this, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSE1X_BmTbY

Answer (score 0):

You may present interface controller modally. In this case, no time is displayed at the top.

Comment: thanks a lot! This worked.  Previously I was using:
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["game"], contexts: nil)

and now I switched it to:
presentController(withName: "game", context: nil)

...which I believe always presents modally. Thanks again!

Comment: ah, actually, when I do this (presentController), I don't get a truly "full screen", because the watch makes room for the "cancel" button that takes me back to the original view controller. So. while the time is gone, I don't actually get more real estate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Choose "Full Screen" from the storyboard and present the controller like below, (Tested with Watch OS 7.2)

```
presentController(withName: "NumberPadController", context: self)
```

Comment: Do not work. :-/