# Gestures like tap and drag don’t work on apple watch’s digit clock area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-watch

I’m working on a full-screen Apple watch app. According to these answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067952), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336885), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56429165)), it’s not possible to hide the top-right digit clock. My question is, is it possible to listen to gestures that started at the clock area, like tap and drag? Based on my test, gestures can be triggered at everywhere except that area. Below is the demo code:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .center){
            Text("Test")
        }
        .frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            maxHeight: .infinity,
            alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.cyan)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .onTapGesture {location in
            print("tap at: \(location)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Tap area demo]

Thanks.

Comment: This is a feature?

Comment: do you really want to allow the touches on the clock?

Comment: @GrandSirr Yes, there are some actions that will let users touch anywhere on the watch screen to trigger.